# Does the volume of an object affect space-time curvature?

Tags: gravity, spacetime

If I have 2 bodies of same mass (100 tonnes). Both have different volumes, let one be $1m^3$ of volume and the other be $10,00,000m^3$. Which would have more gravity.

Consider here that affect of gravity by more dense object diminish to → 0 at about 100m.

Will curvature of space due to two bodies be different at, say 100 m, distance?

Can someone show it pictorially?

To be more clear:

Let the first body have a radius of 1m.
Its field diminish at 100 m to 0. Let the other body have a radius of 1000m (same mass).

At a distance of 1000m, i.e. on surface of second body, would these people feel the same gravity, nearly 0, as he would feel due to small size mass, even if he is so near to body now?

Comment: The field outside the matter distribution is the same (assuming spherical distributions). Not sure why you want to use general relativity to begin with. This is not a strong field problem. Newton is just fine.

Comment: @CuriousOne Inside it will depend on the exact matter content of the body.

Comment: So the answer is, in general, yes.

Comment: @0celo7: Take a look at what the OP wrote in detail. He is setting up unphysical scenarios left and right.

Comment: left and right?

Comment: Umm why would the object with larger volume exert more gravity? Your question makes no sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the objects are spherical then provided you are outside the object its gravity is the same as a point mass located at the centre of the object. See the [Wikipedia article on the shell theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_theorem) for more details. So at the same distance $d$ from the centre of the two objects, and outside them, the gravitational force is the same.

This is a classical result, but in GR we have the similar principle that [outside a spherical mass the geometry is described by the Schwarzschild metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birkhoff%27s_theorem_(relativity)), and again this depends only on the mass. So outside the objects the spacetime curvature as a function of distance is the same.